# Importing a mesh from Make Human to blender and now it doesn't have vertices when I go to edit mode

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, makehuman

I used MakeHuman to quickly build a character and now going to fine tune some things in Blender but when I imported it and go to edit mode the mesh changes position 90 degrees and I can only select the bones of it not the actual mesh.

In wireframe I see it has many vertices and such but none are selectable. It is NOT hidden. I've tried hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: Please provide your .blend file to be able to help you

Comment: If you can only select bones are you not entering edit mode on the armature instead of the mesh?

Comment: I found out it is not really disappearing, its just rotating 90 degrees along the axis. It is actually going off my screen when I am close up... but why would it do that? Like its changing 'up ' direction from Z Axis to Y Axis or something?

Comment: How to add by blend file, sorry - I'm a noob. Just got started about 2 weeks ago.

Comment: I think the edit mode thing is part of the problem. I'm working with it. the 90 degree turn is crazy, but I am making small edits.